# matplotlib module installed, but not found

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to use matplotlib, but I'm getting an ImportError saying module not found even though it is installed.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm running it on Win 7 32-bit through Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: What command are you using to import it?

Comment: I'm just using: 

import matplotlib

if it helps, I'm using python 3.4 and I installed using "pip install"

Comment: Is it listed when you do pip freeze?

Comment: @Semih, when pip freeze I get:

beautifulsoup4==4.4.0  
decorator==4.0.2
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
networkx==1.10
numpy==1.9.2
pandas==0.16.2
path.py==8.1
pickleshare==0.5
Pillow==2.9.0
pylab==0.1.3
pyzmq==14.7.0
requests==2.7.0
scikit-image==0.11.3
scikit-learn==0.16.1
scipy==0.16.0
seaborn==0.6.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
sympy==0.7.6
tornado==4.2.1
traitlets==4.0.0
wheel==0.24.0

I don't see matplotlib it there.  Any advice?

Comment: I am just speculating but, could there be any other Python version installed in your system? It seems that matplotlib is not installed.

Comment: Try to install it again by doing pip install matplotlib and see if it fails.

Comment: @semih just did and said requirement already satisfied - I see the folder for matplotlib in my site-packages area if that's helpful

Comment: So from there can you try again and do this: from matplotlib import *

Comment: @semih is the * supposed to denote something?  Regardless, when I try it still says no module named

Comment: * denotes all that is under that module.

Comment: Ah I c, but yea module still not found.  I checked for other python installs and I only have one

Answer (score 0):

Try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib#Examples. Maybe that is what you are looking for.